# How can I make an atomic statement in Twincat3 PLC?

Tags: plc, twincat

I am working with a fast loop (0.5 ms cycle time) and slow loop (10 ms cycle time) which communicate with each other.
How can I make the in- and outputs to be consistent?

Consider the example below, I want the assignments in the SlowLoop to be atomic, to be sure that both referenced inputs from the FAST loop correspond with values from the same cycle.

##### Example

##### FastLoop [0.5 ms]

```
FAST_CNT = some rising edge detection
FAST_RUNIDX += 1
```

##### SlowLoop [10 ms]

```
<-- Atomic Operation
pulseCount = FAST_CNT
elapsedTicks = FAST_RUNIDX 
Atomic Operation -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Anytime that anything needs to be 'Atomic', you need to handle an object (STRUCT or FUNCTION_BLOCK).
In this case as there is no associated logic, a STRUCT should do the job nicely.

```
TYPE st_CommUnit :
STRUCT
    Count       : UINT;
    Index       : UINT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

You can then have this STRUCT be presented as either an Input or Output between tasks using the %Q* and %I* addressing.

```
- Fast Task - 
SourceData AT %Q* : st_CommUnit
```

```
- Slow Task - 
TargetData AT %I* : st_CommUnit
```

Using this you end up with a linkable object such that you can link:

- The entire unit
- Each individual component

[image: Example Atomic Unit]

Answer (score 2):

If you use two different tasks with different cycle times maybe also running on different cores, you need a way to synchronize the two tasks when doing read/write operations.

In order to access the data in an atomic way use the synchronization FBs that Beckhoff provides like for example FB_IecCriticalSection.
More info here on the infosys Website:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/45844579955484184843.html&id=